# File will not render .get() request on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, handlebars.js

I am attempting simple Express routing and having trouble. I want the server to render the file 'layout2.hbs' into the server when I type in '/1' - but instead the console returns a 304

My error message:

```
GET / 304 30.902 ms - -
GET /style.css 304 3.370 ms - -
GET /print2.css 304 0.553 ms - -
GET /1 304 9.213 ms - -
```

My index.js file that has the routing:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('monk')('localhost:27017/');
var userData = db.get('user-data');
var app = require('express')();

router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('layout');
});

router.get('/1', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('layout2');
});

router.use(express.static("public"));

module.exports = router;
```

My app.js to show handlebars is indeed set up:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var path = require('path');
var port = require('port');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
const queryString = require('query-string');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

My file directory:

```
Bloodborne Backend (project folder)
      │
      |
      |   
    public------print2.css
      |         style.css     
      |           
      | 
      |   
    routes-------index.js
      |
      |
      |
    views-------layout.hbs
      |         layout2.hbs
      |
      |
    app.js
  package.json
```

Sorry if the directory tree looks bad - this is the best way I could type it out.

I expect that when I type in '/1' into my localhost, the file 'layout2.hbs' will render. However, I instead get a 304 implying the server did not change. i've been stuck for a while and cannot figure out a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure why your code is not working however there are a few things that need to be corrected.

The express app is being generated twice in the app.js file, once will suffice.

The static folder only needs to be registerd once in the main app.js file.

I extracted the relevant pieces of code and created a simple working example around your directory structure.

```
projectFolder
  node_modules
    ...
  public
    image.jpg
    style.css
    ...
  routes
    routes.js
    ...
  views
    layout.hbs
    one.hbs
    two.hbs
    ...
  package.json
  app.js
```

app.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');

const router = require('./routes/routes.js' );

const app = express();

app.engine('hbs', hbs({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views' }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')) );

app.use('/', router );

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: err
  });
});

app.listen( 4444 );
```

routes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
  res.render('one' );
});

router.get('/1', function(req,res,next){
  res.render('two');
});

module.exports = router;
```

layout.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Default Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
    <img src="image.jpg" width="200px">
</body>
</html>
```

one.hbs

```
<p> Fragment added from one.hbs </p>
```

two.hbs

```
<p> Fragment added from two.hbs </p>
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

@Hitesh Lala solved the problem! What I did was to change my `defaultLayout` in my `app.js` file to an hbs file called `index.hbs`.  From there my `index.js` file would properly route the correct hbs files - in my case `layout.hbs` and `layout2.hbs`.